# Is $\mathbb{R^n}/{\mathbb{Z}^n}$ homeomorphic to a cup?

Tags: general-topology

If yes, can you explain it to me?

---

Note: *cup* as in *drinking container*.

Comment: What is a cup? ${}{}$

Comment: A drinking container

Comment: Then no in general

Comment: Since a cup is 3-dimensional, it could only happen if $n=3$.  Your quotient, when $n=3$ is a torus ("ring doughnut") which is topologically equivalent to a one-piece cup with handle since you could deform the body of the cup into a long tube connected at either end to the handle (the "hole" in the handle through which your fingers go becomes the hole in the torus).

Comment: Depends on the $n$ and the cup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean the following by a cup, then a cup is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, but not for $n \neq 2$.

[image]

Comment: This makes more sense, I probably wrote the exercise wrong